# MediaPlayer null point exception on some devices

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, media-player

A user on Google Play rated my app one star because it crashes when clicking a button. He is using a HTC Desire 500. I checked his LogCat and it says:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.lifeapps.appquiz.SixthImageLogo$4.onClick(SixthImageLogo.java:333)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4107)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17160)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On line 333 there is MediaPlayer. I don't know what it's causing this issue, because i can't check it on a real device as seen that it works on every other device (mine too of course).

That's the MediaPlayer code inside OnClick:

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SixteenthImageLogo.this, R.raw.twinkle);
    mediaPlayer.start();
       mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.release();
            }
       });
```

The error is on mediaPlayer.start();

raw file is .mp3 and 308.882 bytes.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Giulio, I have a similar problem, only a single user who can't create de MEdiaPlayer, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create()` method can return null according to the documentation. It can happens for example when there are too mediaplayer instances (maybe you are not releasing resources calling `release()` method or you are creating too many instances). So you have to do a check:

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SixteenthImageLogo.this, R.raw.twinkle);
 if (mediaPlayer == null)
       return; //error handling here
```

Bella app ;)

Comment: (Grazie!) I'll ask the user to try it again, and i'll check if my code is now correct. I've added "if (mediaPlayer == null) return;" else "mediaPlayer.start" and so on. I've added mp = null; after mp.release(); too. Thank you for your help, i will give you the point when he confirms it's working.

Comment: Firstly, it seems like it's working, but it returns null anyway. So, he is not able to reproduce my raw files. Secondly, he is experiencing A LOT of issues which do not happen to anyone else: even a simple counter, linked to a more simple SharedPreferences code, it's not working at all. I don't know how to develop on his device, it's like a different Android.

Comment: Maybe it has got a custom ROM

Comment: He doesn't, and that's strange.